# Extract all <a> from table with DOMdocument

Tags: php, domdocument

I want to extract the multiple  `<a>` tags from this html markup:

```
<table align="center" width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"><tr>
<td align="left" width="60%" valign="top">
<font size="5" color="#939390">title</font><br><font size="5" color="#939390">LINKS</font>
<a style="color:#000000;" title="title Link 1" href="/page/242808/1/44643.html">  <b style="background:#ff6633">Link 1</b></a>
<a style="color:#000000;" title="title Link 2" href="/page/242808/2/erewe.html">  <b style="background:#ff6633">Link 2</b></a> 
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and here is my code :

```
      $doc = new DOMDocument(); // create DOMDocument
          libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
          $doc->validateOnParse = true;
          $doc->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
          $doc->loadHTML($html); // load HTML you can add $html           

          $selector = new DOMXPath($doc);
          $a = $selector->query('//table[1]//a')->item(0);
          echo $doc->saveHTML($a);
```

This gets the first `<a>`, but what I want is to get all the `<a>` tags in the document.

Comment: So, you want `//table[1]//a` instead of `//table[1]//a[1]`? And then _loop_ through your query result, rather then just fetching the first one?

Comment: @Wrikken I want to get all <a> in the code above

Comment: ... for which I gave you 2 big hints...

Comment: @Wrikken how to loop thru it can u suggest

Comment: I'd go for a `foreach`... [Can you see the example in the documentation?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get more than one, you'll need to loop through the results instead of just printing the first one:

```
$a = $selector->query('//table[1]//a');

foreach($a as $current) {
    echo $doc->saveHTML($current);
}
```

Comment: Thank u so much, how can i edit the style of the <a> like this `<b style="background:#ff6633">Link 1</b> `